# Eliminar propiedad css de un solo elemento

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Buen día tengo el siguiente código css

```
input {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

lo que hago es que todo elemento input reciba la propiedad `uppercase` y así registrar todos los datos en mayúscula, esto en todos mis formularios, en un formulario tengo un input que quisiera conservar tal cual lo escriba el usuario, como puedo excluir ese input Password de esta regla sin modificar mi regla Css existente, ya que quisiera evitar convertirla en una clase

```
.Mayusculas{
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

para no tener que ir a cada input de mi proyecto y asignarlo a cada input

como información adicional mi proyecto es en ASP.NET MVC

Comment: En lugar de agregar una clase para todos los inputs, porque no la agregas al Password?

Comment: Si lo escribes directamente en el <input style="text-transform:none !important;"> deberia ser suficiente... tosco pero util

Comment: @masterguru me funciono, muchas gracias!

Comment: Observación no menor: Transformar a mayúsculas con CSS no significa que también esté convirtiendo el texto real a mayúsculas. _Es nada más "maquillaje"_.

Comment: ok ok, esa información me es útil al final el texto se envía tal como se escribió cierto?

Comment: Tal cual @Oscar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrega otra clase al tag del password, y en css lo editas. Ejmp:

```
input {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
input.password{
    text-transform:none;
}
```

Comment: [Especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: muchas gracias !